# NHibernate over Mono in Unity3d, connection string problems

Tags: nhibernate, unity-game-engine, mono, compiled

I'm using NHibernate in Unity, and running the project in the debug environment works great, but when running the compiled EXE, I was getting a `NullReferenceException` when trying to access the database.

After much research, I was able to run the following:

```
Debug.LogError(db.Access.mrefSession.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

When running in the editor, I get a nice connection string in the console:

> Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TheDB;User ID=yy;Password=xxxx

When running the compiled EXE, however, this property is null.

What am I missing?

Comment: how do you configure NHibernate? config file,app.config, in code?

Comment: @Firo I hae a convention-based code configurator, but that's not germane to the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some violent trial and error, I was able to get this to work. The solution is deceptively simple: I18N.dll and I18N.West.dll are missing from the standard player. I copied them from the Unity Editor folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0) into the project's Assets\Plugins folder, and everything worked.

I got the hint for this here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/42955/codepage-1252-not-supported-works-in-editor-but-no.html

Comment: Hey João, I am currently also trying to use NHibernate inside of Unity3d, but I had no success getting it to work. Could you share how you set up your project and which version of NHibernate you are using? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jony Couple of things you have to do: 1) make sure your API Compatibility Level is at full 2.0, rather than 2.0 subset; 2) you need to get hold of an older NHibernate version, that targets .NET 2. I'm using 3.3; 3) you have to put the NHibernate DLL and all required dependencies in the somewhere in the Assets folder of your Unity project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! My only problem was that i was using NHibernate 3.4 which is build against .net 3.5. With NHibernate 3.3 everything works flawlessly. Again thank you for your help, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Sorry but I found that it doesn't actually work with NHibernate 3.3 for me either nor with 3.0 nor 2.1. With all version I get the following error: `ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:112)
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.GetDefaultConfigurationFilePath ()
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure ()
NHibernateTest.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/NHibernateTest.cs:43)` I changed to use .net 2.0 in unity

Comment: @Jony Ah. that looks like a configuration error. Are you using XML configuration files? Alas, I'm using a convention-based mapping-by-code class that builds the configuration by reflection, so I'm afraid I can't really help you much, but there should be a place somewhere where you tell the runtime where to find the files...

Comment: Also, I'm not using NHibernate directly from Unity scripts. I built a class library that uses NHibernate, with services that mask it, so that I don't have to actually refer to NHibernate from scripts in the Assets folder. I couldn't get *that* to work either...

Comment: Ah ok thank you lots of useful information. I guess I will also try a class library then. And I guess you are using FluentNHibernate or what exactly to you mean with mapped-by-code?

Comment: @Jody NHibernate has its own map-by-code API, now. Fluent still works, if you're used to it, but I use the native API. Also, I have a convention based mapper that I got from somewhere, then modified heavily for my own purposes. But my point about the class library is, you should test it in a non-Unity environment (such as a WinForms app) so that you know that any non-Unity problems are solved before diving into the Unity-related ones. :)

Comment: Didn't knew that NHibernate has its own map-by-code API. I tested my configuration in a console application and it worked just fine. I found a pull request on the Log4Net github: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/320 it looks like a related issue and if I am not mistaken NHibernate uses Log4Net for its logging (or at least it used to). So maybe I need to create a Log4Net configuration, but how would NHibernate know to use my configuration... I think for the time being I will just try to use a dll and "wrap" NHibernate with it. Also thanks for all your time and effort, I really appreciate it.

Comment: After doing a lot more research and trial and error I got NHibernate working inside of Unity3d directly. First you need to download the source of NHibernate 3.x.x, I used 3.4.0. Then in the `Logging.cs in line 85` you need to change `baseDir` to equal `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`. After that compile the project and put the dlls in the Assets folder of your project  and lastly you need to add the .net connector for the database you are using, MySQL.Data.dll in my case. After that everything worked fine for me inside the Editor, Win and Mac builds. Just thought you might be interested.

Comment: @Jony Good for you. I +1'd your comment. Modifying NHibernate was outside the scope of my project, though, so I couldn't go that route. In any case, grats, and I hope I helped. :)